# Effective way to merge contacts

Tags: contacts

Well, I suffer with that issue of merging contacts - name, phone, e-mail, birthday etc. info.

1. I backed up all my old phone contacts to Google Contacts (my old contacts were on a XLS file, so I converted it to CSV and imported it on http://mail.google.com/contacts ).
2. I already had a lot of Google Contacts, because of the bad default option to add everyone I sent an e-mail before...
3. I try to automerge contacts on Google Contacts, but it often merge wrong ones...
4. Merging manually on Google Contacts is so boring...
5. I tried some apps from Google Play to merge contacts, but they often merge wrong ones too...

Do you know a effective way to merge them automagically?

Comment: Well, as you've discovered (as I did), when your source data is a mess automated tools can only go so far. Your best bet is to continue to massage the data in Google Contacts to get it straightened out. Otherwise you're probably looking at an expensive automated solution or, more realistically, hiring human(s) to do it for you.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [other 23 related questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[contacts]+merge+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1) on merging contacts which already have answers. With some luck, they might give you a good hint.